# Programmatically make plot areas have the same dimensions in Plotly Dash dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

While the below two graphs are rendered in the same container `div`, it seems the axis labeling (amongst the other things???) is causing the actual render area to be smaller on the top plot

[image: axis label wrong]

When the axis is modified this somewhat corrects:

[image]

Ultimately I'm wondering if its possible to make the plot areas be exactly the same width (regardless of axis titles/labels/etc)?

Here's the relevant code that goes with the above explanation:

```py
    ...

html.Div([
    html.Div(
        id="row-1-2",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='plot1',
                        style={"height": "20vh", "margin": "0px"},
                    ),
                ],
                className="twelve columns",
            )
        ],
        className="row",
        style={"margin": "0px"},
    ),
    html.Div(
        id="row-2-2",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='plot2',
                        style={"height": "20vh", "margin": "0px"},
                    ),
                ],
                className="twelve columns",
            )
        ],
        className="row",
        style={"margin": "0px"},
    ),
], className="three columns"),

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS property width to render same width graph sizes like -

```
html.Div([
    html.Div(
        id="row-1-2",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='plot1',
                        style={"height": "20vh", "width":"80vw", margin": "0px"},
                    ),
                ],
                className="twelve columns",
            )
        ],
        className="row",
        style={"margin": "0px"},
    ),
    html.Div(
        id="row-2-2",
        children=[
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Graph(
                        id='plot2',
                        style={"height": "20vh", "width":"80vw", "margin": "0px"},
                    ),
                ],
                className="twelve columns",
            )
        ],
        className="row",
        style={"margin": "0px"},
    ),
], className="three columns"),

    ...
```

Comment: still have the same problem, and it messes with the bootstrap config so they're sized incorrectly based on `div` styling

Answer (score 0):

seems like the closest I can get it is by setting `automargin` to false in the actual figure:

```py
fig.update_layout({"xaxis": {"automargin": False}})
```

[image]